# Mobile device screen width discrepancies

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have Huawei G620S. The [spec](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_g620s-6677.php) says that the display resolution is 720 x 1280 pics. Now when i explicitly set the width of an element like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("width: "+screen.width);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
        .div1 {
            width: 1280px;
            height: 120px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <b>To understand this example, you should open this page on a
                phone or a tablet.</b>
        </p>
    
        <div class="div1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `div1` elem takes the entire width of the screen (not a half of it) as if the display res. was 640, not 1280. The `screen.width` property also gives 640 not 1280. So what's the real screen width of the device?

My specs: Huawei G620S on Android 4.4.4 on Chrome 57.0.2987.132

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but can you try to use `vw` and `vh` units for measurement? So half of screen would be `50vw` and so on. Hope it helps.

Comment: You may also need to understand the concept of "device pixels". It sounds like the device is 1280 pixels wide (in landscape?) but uses a device pixel ratio of @2x. Meaning 1280px = 640px...

Comment: You can check what your mobile says at https://mydevice.io (what he is is another story)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Does it mean that if the device pixel ratio is @2 as you've suggested the smallest display union i can address is 2 physical pixels?

Comment: _"Display union"_?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i mean display unit, sorry

Comment: @Mulligun81 I think I might be. Although I'm not sure what would happen if you supplied `0.5px`. I recommend doing some tests.